# How to Adjust y axis plot range in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, plot

I need to plot the following functions in matlab

```
y1=sign(x)
y2=tanh(x)
y3=(x)/(x+1)
```

The x-range is -5,5 with 0.1 spacing
The y-plot range should be between -1.5 to 1.5.

Each plot should have a labeled x and y axis and a legend in the lower right corner.

The only things I cant figure out is how to adjust the y plot range. Ive tried editing the actual figure but all that seems to do is distort the graph. 
Is there a command within matlab that will let me adjust the y axis plot range?

The other thing I havent figured out yet is adding a legend, I can do it after the figure is created but I guess it needs to be done by matlab command.

Comment: Did you check the help file for `legend`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, use [`axis`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/axis.html) after the `plot` command:

```
axis([-5 5 -1.5 1.5])
```

Comment: You can also do `set(gca,'YLim',[-1.5 1.5])`

Comment: I think your proposals are not sufficient etc `YLim` because you do not transform/scale the data to the wanted range. Please, show complete answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you only want to set the y-range without setting the x-range you can use

```
ylim([-1.5 1.5])
```

or alternatively `axis([-inf inf -1.5 1.5])`. I found this from the original MATLAB-source: https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ylim.html

PS: For trigonometric functions I would recommend to use `axis equal` to have equally spaced x and y-axis (see [MATLAB](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axis.html#buk989s-1-style))