# Set y axis limits matlab plot

Tags: matlab, graph, normal-distribution

I have the following normal distribution and i need to set the graph plot to 1.5 on y axis.

```
x = -.5:0.0001:3.5;
m1 = 1;
s1 = 0.5;
pdfNormal_1 = normpdf(x, m1, s1);
ylim([0 1.5])
set(gcf,'color','w');
plot(x, pdfNormal_1)%, x, pdfNormal_2);
```

Could someone tell me how to? Regards

Comment: Try to use ylim after the plot command.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Adjust y axis plot range in Matlab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21529467/how-to-adjust-y-axis-plot-range-in-matlab)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `axis` function is the one you need.

you can set the axis to the values you want using

```
axis([xmin xmax ymin ymax])
```

or you can play with it doing things like:

```
axis equal
axis tight
axis off
```

etc

Go to the documentation for more info:

http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/axis.html?refresh=true

Comment: I cannot set the y sup limit to 1.5. It sets for 1 automatically.

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
x = -.5:0.0001:3.5;
m1 = 1;
s1 = 0.5;
pdfNormal_1 = normpdf(x, m1, s1);
set(gcf,'color','w');
plot(x, pdfNormal_1)%, x, pdfNormal_2);
ylim([0 1.5])
```

Comment: I didn't see @zinjaai 's comment.